# graphicsmagick error in imread function of octave 3.6.4

Tags: octave, graphicsmagick

I am running Octave 3.6.4 32 bit on Ubuntu 13.10 of a 64bit machine when getting this error.

Here are a few examples:

```
>>> imread('1505.jpg')
warning: your version of GraphicsMagick limits images to 8 bits per pixel
error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick: Unable to open f
ile (jpg) reported by magick/constitute.c:1533 (ReadImage)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7

>>>imread("/home/simona/Documents/Work/Marshall_TC_ID/1505.jpg")
error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick: Unable to open f
ile (jpg) reported by magick/constitute.c:1533 (ReadImage)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7

>>> imread('LGH.png')
error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick: Unable to open f
ile (ng) reported by magick/constitute.c:1533 (ReadImage)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7

>>> imread('sample1.png')
error: imread: invalid image file: Magick++ exception: Magick: Unable to open f
ile (e1.png) reported by magick/blob.c:2779 (OpenBlob)
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/image/imread.m at line 74, column 7
```

From what I've read in similar problems, this seems to be coming from Graphicsmagick, or more precisely, erroneous interaction between Octave and graphicsmagick. 
It is interesting that in synaptic package manager, I found graphicsmagick package to be not installed, but some libgraphicsmagick package was. Even after installing that package, I still get the same error. 
Re-installing Octave does not help either. 
The images I use worked well with Matlab on Windows machines.

One thing I find weird is that in the error message, 'Unable to open file (filename) reported by...' the filename was never completely shown. Does this mean the filename was not correctly given?
Also, there were two types of errors in above examples. One in the end says (ReadImage) while the other says (OpenBlob).

Similar errors seem to be usually resolved by re-building graphicsmagick with appropriate configuration. However, I don't know how to find out its current configuration. It would be very helpful if someone with better knowledge about graphicsmagick can lend a hand. Because I think I need to know which part of graphicsmagick is not working in order to fix it.

Does anyone have some ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be losing the first 5 bytes of each filename.  What happens if you do "imread(XXXXXsample1.png)"?  Not suggesting that as a workaround, but the result might help us debug the thing.

Answer (score -1):

try changing the image file and check the lines again. Usually there will not be any problem in loading.

Comment: What does that mean?  It already failed on four different files.